# How can I use two-dimensional data as input to Conv1D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Here is my code

```
def create_dataset(signal_data, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(signal_data) - look_back):
        dataX.append(signal_data[i:(i + look_back), :])
        dataY.append(signal_data[i + look_back, -1])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)


look_back = 200




stock = 'a.csv'
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

df = pd.read_csv(stock)


signal_data = df[["close"]].values.astype('float32')



signal_data = scaler.fit_transform(signal_data)

train_size = int(len(signal_data) * 0.80)
test_size = len(signal_data) - train_size

train = signal_data[0:train_size]
test = signal_data[train_size:]

x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
x_test, y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)


CNN = Sequential()
CNN.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(None, 200)))
CNN.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
CNN.add(Flatten())
```

`x_train` and `y_train` have shapes (1399, 200, 1), (1399) by create_dataset.

But Conv1D accepts input in three dimensions.

To solve this, I tried to set `input_shape = (None, 200)` (since loock_back is 200).

but, this method occurs a `ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, 16). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your mode`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try 200 1 as input To first Layer

If I understand correct , 1399 is the batch size right?

When using Conv1D as the first layer in a model, provide an input_shape argument (tuple of integers or None, e.g. (10, 128) for sequences of 10 vectors of 128-dimensional vectors, or (None, 128) for variable-length sequences of 128-dimensional vectors.
if your sequences  is 200 you can set (200 ,1) ignore the batch size